# family tree /3 prolog

Tags: prolog, family-tree

I'm sort of a beginner to Prolog and I have a quick question. I've built a family tree in prolog with parents(X,Y,Z). But when time comes to built uncle(Uncle,X). and aunt(Aunt,X). seems a bit difficult for me. I've tried uncle(Uncle,X) :- first_cousins(X,Y),parents(Y,Uncle,_). and aunt(Aunt,X) :- first_cousins(X,Y),parents(Y,_,Aunt). but it brings me out the same outcome several times before proceeding to the next one. So, I was thinking something like with four sentences for each one. Any thoughts?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: i finally came down to this

Comment: uncle(Uncle,X) :- parents(X,A,_),siblings(A,Uncle),male(Uncle).
 uncle(Uncle,X) :- parents(X,_,B),siblings(B,Uncle),male(Uncle).
 uncle(Uncle,X) :- parents(X,A,_),siblings(A,Aunt),parents(_,Uncle,Aunt).
 uncle(Uncle,X) :- parents(X,_,B),siblings(B,Uncle),parents(_,Uncle,_).

 aunt(Aunt,X) :- parents(X,A,_),siblings(A,Uncle),parents(_,Uncle,Aunt).
 aunt(Aunt,X) :- parents(X,_,B),siblings(B,Uncle),parents(_,Uncle,Aunt).
 aunt(Aunt,X) :- parents(X,A,_),siblings(A,Aunt),female(Aunt).
 aunt(Aunt,X) :- parents(X,_,B),siblings(B,Aunt),female(Aunt).

Comment: uncle runs just fine . Although aunt needs a little adjustment because gives double answers